# Analysis of variance for binary data

Tags: anova, variance, multivariate-analysis, binary-data, paired-data

I was wondering if there is a test for binary data similar to two-way ANOVA. Basically, I have 50 images analyzed by 3 persons using 2 different methods and thus I obtained 6 samples of paired/dependent binary measurements. What test I can use to compare the variation between these?
Thanks

Comment: What is your question? Are you interested in if the rates are the same? Or are you interested in something more complex to test, eg, agreement of raters, methods, or both? Is this about radiographic findings?

Comment: searches on *glm anova binomial* or *glm anova binary* or *glm anova bernoulli* should turn up a number of relevant answers

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. David, I would be interested in the agreement of methods AND the agreement of raters, if possible. It is indeed radiographic findings. I know you can use McNeman and Cochran's Q correspondingly, but because there are multiple comparisons I was looking for something ANOVA-like to take account of that.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the goal of your research, a [generalized linear model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model) may be of interest to you. With this you can uncover variation in main effects and interactions of your design.

A plain generalized linear model (GLM) can be fit in R via the command `glm()`. In the first argument you'll want to define your model, which is usually done via forumula for simplicity. An example would be `DV ~ IV1*IV2`. This would fit your dependent variable, `DV` as a function of your two independent terms terms. Additionally, the `*` symbol implies inclusion of an interaction between these two terms, whereas `+` would only include their main effects.

You'll also want to define what type, or distribution of GLM you're utilizing via the `family` argument. In your case since you're using binomial data you'll want to set `family = binomial`. Now say you want to set the type of binomial regression to `probit` rather than `logit` (the default for binomial GLM), you'll need to change the link of the family like so: `family = binomial(link = "probit")`.

Finally, here's an example of a binomial outcome data set with a logit regression fitted.

`foo <- data.frame("IV1"=rnorm(100), "IV2"=log(runif(100)), "DV"=rbinom(100, 1, .5))
model <- glm(DV ~ IV1*IV2, data=foo, family=binomial(link = "logit"))
model
summary(model)`

Comment: This is presently overly brief, amounting to little more than a link, which makes it more of a comment than an answer (I was just about to post a comment with more detail than your answer). Can you please offer a brief sentence or two in addition to what you have to outline the most salient parts of how to do this with a GLM?

Comment: Some intuitive and simple approaches are discussed in BBR Chapter 16 - see link at http://www.fharrell.com/p/blog-page.html

Comment: Thanks Connor, this is very helpful. Is there a nice documentation explaining how to interpret the results of the GLM?

Comment: May I ask a follow-up question? What is the difference between GLM and binary logistic regression? It seems I can also use the latter for testing associations between my dependent variable, binary measurements, and both the raters and methods. When should each of these tests used?

Comment: In the context of the analysis I described above, you are fitting a binary logistic regression **via** a generalized linear model. To be honest, I'm not the best person to give a complete rundown of the differences, but you can read more about the topic here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression#As_a_generalized_linear_model

Comment: Correct link is https://hbiostat.org/bbr